Repairing holes in my hardwood floor
My home is a hundred and one years old. I have some pretty large holes in my flooring, about three inches in diameter, that have the wood gone and foam underlayment showing through. How do I repair this?

Three inches sounds like drain water pipe size.  Can use a hole saw to cut a similar like size from excess/new matching wood.  Foam underneath sounds more modern, like for a floating floor, LVP/laminate.  Pictures will help.

Foam wasn't used a hundred years ago, so the flooring with holes is not that old.  Are you sure it is wood and not a laminate?  Pics would help here.

If you want it to look good the best approach is probably to cut the damaged boards at the joists and replace them with similar boards.

Material and tools needed
Floor plank in matching stile
Circular saw at about 3 inches diameter
Cut disks that you can insert in the holes
Finish with wood filler

Old floors made out of pine, as time goes by the knots get detached and you get those semi-circular holes. In my experience working with old floors the best solution is to do a dutchman repair. There are many online guides, for example https://www.thisoldhouse.com/flooring/21017475/how-to-patch-a-chipped-wood-floor-2.

Not sure the floor is old pine given the foam underlay...
